# Errors involving the location of variables

Tags: string, variables, loops, math

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MathFun {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int x = 0;

        System.out.println(" Enter a math operation: ");
        String expr = input.next();

        int pos = expr.indexOf("+");

        if ( pos >= 0) {
            int op1 = Integer.parseInt(expr.substring(0, pos));
            int op2 = Integer.parseInt(expr.substring( pos - x , expr.length()));
            System.out.println( op1 + op2);
            } else 
            if (pos == expr.indexOf("-")) {
            int op1 = Integer.parseInt(expr.substring(0, pos));
            int op2 = Integer.parseInt(expr.substring( pos - x , expr.length()));
            System.out.println( op1 - op2);
            } else
            if (pos == expr.indexOf("/")) {
            int op1 = Integer.parseInt(expr.substring(0, pos));
            int op2 = Integer.parseInt(expr.substring( pos - x , expr.length()));
            System.out.println( op1 / op2); 
            } else 
            if (pos == expr.indexOf("%")) {
            int op1 = Integer.parseInt(expr.substring(0, pos));
            int op2 = Integer.parseInt(expr.substring( pos - x , expr.length()));
            System.out.println( op1 % op2);
            } 
            else {
            System.out.println(" Invalid operation ");
                }
            }       
    }
```

ALthough this goes through javac, the program automatically says

```
an ex out of range: -1
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1937)
at MathFun.main(MathFun.java:21)
```

Is there something wrong with the loop?
I just want to make a simple loop that lets the user enter a string 2+2 and let the loop read that out as a string and print the result. Thank You!

Comment: `Is there something wrong with the loop?` where is the loop

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things going wrong in your code.

1. `string expr = in.next();` should be `String expr = in.next();`
2. You are using `pos` variable before you declare it. Serious error.
3. `int pos = expr.indexOf();` //Index of what??
4. Your Scanner name is `input` not `in`.

And these are only compile time errors. Fix them and then see how your program behaves

Comment: The program compiles and runs, but it prints an error when i put the string